# C++ - Condição de parada em estrutura de repetição

Tags: c, c++, while

Como colocar esse código em uma estrutura de repetição de modo que após o cálculo seja mostrada a opção "Digite S para sair ou C para continuar"?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
setlocale (LC_ALL, "portuguese");

float soma, div, raiz, sub, escolha, numero1, numero2, pot, multi, loga;
cout << "Digite a operação desejada" << endl;
cout << "(1) Soma| X + Y" << endl;
cout << "(2) Divisão| X / Y" << endl;
cout << "(3) Raiz| RAIZ (X)" << endl;
cout << "(4) Subtração| X - Y" << endl;
cout << "(5) Potência| X^Y" << endl;
cout << "(6) Multiplicação| X * Y" << endl;
cout << "(7) Logaritmo| LOG10(X)" << endl;
cin >> escolha;




if (escolha == 1){
cout << "Digite o valor de 'X': ";
cin >> numero1;
cout << "Digite o valor de 'Y': ";
cin >> numero2;
soma = (numero1 + numero2);
cout << "X + Y = " << soma;
}else if (escolha == 2){
cout << "Digite o valor de 'X': ";
cin >> numero1;
cout << "Digite o valor de 'Y': ";
cin >> numero2;
div = numero1 / numero2;
cout << "X / Y = " << div;
}else if (escolha == 3){
cout << "Digite o valor de 'X': ";
cin >> numero1;
raiz = sqrt(numero1);
cout << "Raiz de (X) = " << raiz;
}else if (escolha == 4){
cout << "Digite o valor de 'X': ";
cin >> numero1;
cout << "Digite o valor de 'Y': ";
cin >> numero2;
sub = numero1 - numero2;
cout << "X - Y = " << sub;
}else if (escolha == 5) {
cout << "Digite o valor de 'X': ";
cin >> numero1;
cout << "Digite o valor de 'Y': ";
cin >> numero2;
pot = pow(numero1, numero2);
cout << "X^Y = " << pot;
}else if (escolha == 6){
cout << "Digite o valor de 'X': ";
cin >> numero1;
cout << "Digite o valor de 'Y': ";
cin >> numero2;
multi = numero1 * numero2;
cout << "X * y = " << multi;
}else if (escolha == 7){
cout << "Digite o valor de 'X': ";
cin >> numero1;
loga = log10(numero1);
cout << "LOG10(X) = " << loga;
}else if (escolha >7){
cout << "Você não escolheu nenhum valor";

}

cout << "\n\n";
cin.get();
system ("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Laço de repetição com um switch. Tente usar while ou do while ao invés de tanto if/else. Veja um bom artigo para aprendizado, caso não conheça http://www.devmedia.com.br/estrutura-de-repeticao-c/24121

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Outra alternativa seria fazer assim, como `while`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    setlocale (LC_ALL, "portuguese");

    float soma, div, raiz, sub, numero1, numero2, pot, multi, loga;
    int escolha = 0; // o case não aceita float/double/strings

    while (escolha >= 0 && escolha <= 7) {
        cout << "Digite a operação desejada" << endl;
        cout << "(1) Soma| X + Y" << endl;
        cout << "(2) Divisão| X / Y" << endl;
        cout << "(3) Raiz| RAIZ (X)" << endl;
        cout << "(4) Subtração| X - Y" << endl;
        cout << "(5) Potência| X^Y" << endl;
        cout << "(6) Multiplicação| X * Y" << endl;
        cout << "(7) Logaritmo| LOG10(X)" << endl;
        cout << "(0) Continuar" << endl;
        cout << "(?) Digite outro número para sair" << endl;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Digite sua escolha: ";
        cin >> escolha;

        switch (escolha) {
            case 1:
                cout << "Digite o valor de 'X': ";
                cin >> numero1;
                cout << "Digite o valor de 'Y': ";
                cin >> numero2;
                soma = (numero1 + numero2);
                cout << "X + Y = " << soma;
                break;
            case 2:
                cout << "Digite o valor de 'X': ";
                cin >> numero1;
                cout << "Digite o valor de 'Y': ";
                cin >> numero2;
                div = numero1 / numero2;
                cout << "X / Y = " << div;
                break;
            case 3:
                cout << "Digite o valor de 'X': ";
                cin >> numero1;
                raiz = sqrt(numero1);
                cout << "Raiz de (X) = " << raiz;
                break;
            case 4:
                cout << "Digite o valor de 'X': ";
                cin >> numero1;
                cout << "Digite o valor de 'Y': ";
                cin >> numero2;
                sub = numero1 - numero2;
                cout << "X - Y = " << sub;  
                break;
            case 5:
                cout << "Digite o valor de 'X': ";
                cin >> numero1;
                cout << "Digite o valor de 'Y': ";
                cin >> numero2;
                pot = pow(numero1, numero2);
                cout << "X^Y = " << pot;
                break;
            case 6:
                cout << "Digite o valor de 'X': ";
                cin >> numero1;
                cout << "Digite o valor de 'Y': ";
                cin >> numero2;
                multi = numero1 * numero2;
                cout << "X * y = " << multi;
                break;
            case 7:
                cout << "Digite o valor de 'X': ";
                cin >> numero1;
                loga = log10(numero1);
                cout << "LOG10(X) = " << loga;
                break;
            default:
                // nada, deixa que passe para a próxima iteração para que a condição seja verificada novamente.
                break;
        }
        cout << "\n\n";
    }

    cout << "Digite qualquer tecla para sair...";
    cin.get();
    system ("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Assim você não precisaria declarar outra variável. Também perceba que eu inicializei escolha com zero pra que a execução entre no laço na primeira vez. Parece-me que você não domina ainda as estruturas de repetição, então  te aconselho a estudar um pouco sobre depois.

Explicando, o código funciona assim: o código dentro do `while` vai rodar sempre que a condição do laço for verdadeira (ao chegar ao fim do bloco, a execução volta pra condição, ela é avaliada, se for verdadeira, ele executa o bloco denovo); os `case` são bem sugestivos, então "caso o número seja 1, faça isso", "caso seja 2, faça aquilo".

**Uma observação importante é que os `case` só podem ser utilizados com tipos literais, ou seja, valores expressos no código mesmo, exceto *strings* (*[?] Referências necessárias*), então alguns dos valores que os `case` aceitam incluem 'a', 1, etc. Perceba que eu modifiquei teu código colocando a var escolha como *int*, porque o switch não aceita números float/double, somente inteiros.**

Outra coisa é os `break`s ao fim de cada  bloco de `case`, você precisa deles; caso contrário, o `case` seguinte seria executado, indica o fim do código de cada `case`. E por fim `default` é como o `else` do `if`, que é executado quando o valor não for nenhum dos anteriores.

Só mais uma coisa, se for compilar num linux deves tirar a inclusão da `conio.h`.

Espero ter sido claro e ajudado.

Answer (score 3):

Neste caso a estrutura mais aconselhável é o do `{} while();`, porque você evita uma verificação que é desnecessária antes da primeira execução do código, já que o programa tem um menu e este será exibido na tela na primeira iteração do seu laço de repetição impreterivelmente. Para atender ao seu problema exatamente da forma como postou pode criar uma variável para armazenar a "resposta" do usuário e testá-la na condição do laço de repetição:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale (LC_ALL, "portuguese");

    float soma, div, raiz, sub, escolha, numero1, numero2, pot, multi, loga;
    char saida;

    do
    {
        cout << "Digite a operação desejada" << endl;
        cout << "(1) Soma| X + Y" << endl;
        cout << "(2) Divisão| X / Y" << endl;
        cout << "(3) Raiz| RAIZ (X)" << endl;
        cout << "(4) Subtração| X - Y" << endl;
        cout << "(5) Potência| X^Y" << endl;
        cout << "(6) Multiplicação| X * Y" << endl;
        cout << "(7) Logaritmo| LOG10(X)" << endl;
        cin >> escolha;




        if (escolha == 1)
        {
            cout << "Digite o valor de 'X': ";
            cin >> numero1;
            cout << "Digite o valor de 'Y': ";
            cin >> numero2;
            soma = (numero1 + numero2);
            cout << "X + Y = " << soma;
        }
        else if (escolha == 2)
        {
            cout << "Digite o valor de 'X': ";
            cin >> numero1;
            cout << "Digite o valor de 'Y': ";
            cin >> numero2;
            div = numero1 / numero2;
            cout << "X / Y = " << div;
        }
        else if (escolha == 3)
        {
            cout << "Digite o valor de 'X': ";
            cin >> numero1;
            raiz = sqrt(numero1);
            cout << "Raiz de (X) = " << raiz;
        }
        else if (escolha == 4)
        {
            cout << "Digite o valor de 'X': ";
            cin >> numero1;
            cout << "Digite o valor de 'Y': ";
            cin >> numero2;
            sub = numero1 - numero2;
            cout << "X - Y = " << sub;
        }
        else if (escolha == 5) 
        {
            cout << "Digite o valor de 'X': ";
            cin >> numero1;
            cout << "Digite o valor de 'Y': ";
            cin >> numero2;
            pot = pow(numero1, numero2);
            cout << "X^Y = " << pot;
        }
        else if (escolha == 6)
        {
            cout << "Digite o valor de 'X': ";
            cin >> numero1;
            cout << "Digite o valor de 'Y': ";
            cin >> numero2;
            multi = numero1 * numero2;
            cout << "X * y = " << multi;
        }
        else if (escolha == 7)
        {
            cout << "Digite o valor de 'X': ";
            cin >> numero1;
            loga = log10(numero1);
            cout << "LOG10(X) = " << loga;
        }
        else if (escolha >7)
        {
            cout << "Você não escolheu nenhum valor";
        }

        cout << "Digite S para sair e C para continuar";
        cin >> saida;

    }while((saida != "S")||(saida != "s"));

    cout << "\n\n";
    cin.get();
    system ("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```